# How to tell fxml to use file in project

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So I have a `.FXML` file and a `.png` file in the same directory.

However, when I try to tell the `.fxml` to use that image I get the following response:

> `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found`

This is the code (line 31 is where the issue is) and the file structuring:

[image]

I've tried to use an Absolute Path and it does not work.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) [also see](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), particularly the part about location resolution

Comment: please never make a photo of your code. consider just posting it in text format.